# How do I remove YouTube sidebar integration?

Tags: unity, youtube

I accidentally agreed to allow Firefox to 'integrate' YouTube with my desktop sidebar and now I want to get rid of it. How do I do this?

Comment: Have you tried right clicking on it and removing it from sthe sitebar?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Tools` > `Add-ons` > `Extensions` > Select yours and disable / delete.

Comment: OK That worked but is obviously an all or nothing fix.

Comment: @Tyler: O.o Something is either enabled (working) or disabled (not working). There's no in-between...

Comment: this is not working on ubuntu 13.10 - there is no option to remove the darn thing!

Comment: @playcat : That's because it has been installed as root (either as a dependency to something or when you installed your base system), and as such it resides somewhere in `/user/share/` (I'm not sure of the exact location so I might be mistaken), and not by your normal user (which would install it somewhere in your home). As such to get rid of it you have to to uninstall it as root (either the package that contains it or the addon from the browser, both seem to work ... though the second one messes up the package mangers little mind a bit).

Comment: thx for explanation.. it might be good to add it as edit to your answer because, to be honest, I found Krishna's answer more useful. if you wrote this explanation - it would change this.

Answer (score 5):

Uninstall **unity-webapps-youtube** via **synaptic** or **apt-get**. Also if there are other site integrations which you want to remove follow the same method 
`sudo apt-get remove unity-webapps-<site_name>`.

Comment: yes! unlike the selected answer, this thing did the job. i have just installed ubuntu and slowly i'm starting to dislike it for these "firefox apps".

Comment: Glad you found it useful.BTW these are *NOT* Firefox apps but unity webapps which helps in deep integration of websites with ubuntu. 
Also can you mark my answer as accepted? It will help me in building my reputation. :-)

Comment: hm :) ... I didn't mark it as accepted because I didn't post the question :). i did upvote it though

Comment: Opps..blunder!! xD